# Jquery change css too late?

Tags: jquery

I have some code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.selector').css({'color':'#cc0000'});
    if(confirm('Do you want to remove')){
        $.ajax({
            ...
        });
    }
    else{
        // $('.selector').css('color','');
    }
});
```

But css change color after "confirm". How it show red color before "confirm"?

Comment: Why do you care? If you are using a dialog then user attention should be on the dialog, not on something on the page that they cannot interact with. Especially if you are just going to change it back as soon as they close the dialog anyway

Comment: I want to show user what he will delete.

Comment: But you can't even be sure the element will be visible on the screen to the user anyway. If you want a nice UX then you probably shouldn't be using the built in confirm dialog in the first place

Comment: I dont understand you. User see all posts. And its good to show user post what he wants to delete

Comment: So all posts will be on screen no matter how small the screen size is? And you are sure the post will never be hidden beneath the confirm dialog? I can't see your design so I can'f offer a better suggestion, I am just saying it doesn't sound like the right way to do it. But that doesn't matter, you just do what you want

Comment: Confirm dialog appears at the top of browser. Its possible that cofrirm dialog will be hide post if post is also at the top and post and screen are small. If text is on the dialog but then if post is very big, dialog will be also very big.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because the `confirm()` is a modal call which blocks the UI thread of the browser from updating. To fix this you can put the `confirm()` in a `setTimeout()` with a very short delay. Also note that you should avoid using `css()` unless there is no alternative. Apply classes instead. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.selector').addClass('active');

  setTimeout(function() {
    if (confirm('Do you want to remove')) {
      $.ajax({
        // ...
      });
    }
    else {
      $('.selector').removeClass('active');
    }
  }, 25);
});
```

```css
.active { color: #C00; }
```

Comment: yes, it works. but it can have little time and css not showing? or it always work?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but you can lower the delay if needed. Reduce the `25` figure. It's the number of milliseconds the timeout will wait before executing.

Comment: i mean than 25ms can have not enough time? in this case it should increase the duration of time. or it always work?

Comment: 25ms should be more than enough. Even 10ms is probably quite generous.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a callback function. Sadly `css()` do not support this. But you can use `animate()` with a time of 0 seconds for that.

```
   $(this).animate({CSS-PARAMETERS},0,function(){
      if(confirm(...)){
        ...
      }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose `setTimeout`

```js
$(document).on('click', '.delete',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.selector').css({'color':'#cc0000'});
    
    setTimeout(function(){
      if(confirm('Do you want to remove')){

      }
    }, 100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="delete selector">Delete?</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.selector').css({'color':'#cc0000'});

    window.setTimeout(function()
    {
        if(confirm('Do you want to remove')){
            $.ajax({
                ...
            });
        }
        else{
            // $('.selector').css('color','');
        }
    }
    , 500);

});
```

Comment: Change the value 500 to your needs.